# Bernoulli's principle doubt

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, bernoulli-equation

Consider two points A and B on a pipe at the same height.
Fluid is in a steady flow inside. 
External pressure is provided at point A and the fluid travels to point B.

The region at point A has a smaller cross section that point B. Therefore, $v_A > v_B $. As,

$ P_A + 1/2 \rho v_A^2 = P_B + 1/2 \rho v_B^2 $

Thus, naturally, pressure at region A is lower than B.

The question is how then is the fluid travelling from A to B when the pressure difference is actually in  opposite direction and flow should be reverse?

Comment: Related: [https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/157038](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/157038/)

Comment: A fluid does not have to travel in the direction of decreasing pressure difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do particles always flow from high to low pressure?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/157038/)